# Output a Realm object name and its realmlist

Tags: java, android, realm

I would like search for my favourite  school names and its favourite student names like the following from my main table.

POINT GREY
kent
jane 
michelle

MAGGEE
gary
john
shirley

However, I can only achieve getting the favourites student names using realm query:

```
RealmResults<Student> fav = realm.where(Student.class)
                              .equalTo("Favourite", "Yes")
                             .findAll();
```

My question is how to list my favourite schools and their favourite students in realm.  Many Thanks.

My School class

```
public class School extends RealmObject {

@Required
private String SchoolID;
private String SchoolName;
private RealmList<Student> Students;

//getters, setters;
```

}

My Student Class

```
public class Student extends RealmObject{

@Required
private String StudentID;
private String StudentName;
private Boolean Favorite;

 //getters, setters;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are looking for is called backlinks, which is an automatic reference between objects. You can see the issue here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607

Until it is implemented you need to either manually maintain a reference from your Student to the School or make a query for it.